# How to put Angular unit tests with Travis (No captured browser)?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, travis-ci

My unit Tests work in my shell with 'ng test', but not with Travis :
[No captured browser in Travis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7Wcw.png)

I am using karma, karma.conf.js :

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'), reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },

    files: [
      { pattern: 'src/app/*.ts', served: true, watched: true, included: false},
      { pattern: 'src/app/**/**/*.spec.ts', served: true, watched: true, included: false}
    ],
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    //browsers: ['Chrome'],
    browsers: ['ChromeNoSandbox'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeNoSandbox: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    },
    singleRun: false,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 25000
  });
};
```

Then, this is my .travil.yml :

```
 language: node_js

sudo: required 
node_js:
  - node

# addons: 
#   chrome: stable
#   firefox: latest

apt:
  sources:
    - google-chrome
  packages:
    - python
    - golang
    - google-chrome-stable
    - google-chrome-beta

before_install:
- wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
- sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
- export CHROME_BIN=usr/bin/google-chrome
- export DISPLAY=:99.0
- sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start



before_script:
- "sudo chown root /opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox"
- "sudo chmod 4755 /opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox"

# No need these two lines if you use latest version of node
# - npm install
# - npm update

- yarn


# - export CHROME_BIN=usr/bin/google-chrome
# - export DISPLAY=:99.0
# - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
# - sudo apt-get update
# - sudo apt-get install -y libappindicator1 fonts-liberation
# - wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
# - sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb


# install:
# - npm install -g @angular/cli

script:
# - npm test
- yarn e2e
- yarn lint
- yarn test
```

I saw many solutions, but nothing works for me.

I don't know if there is a link, but Karma start doesn't work in my project too, with this error : The '@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma' karma plugin is meant to be used from within Angular CLI and will not work correctly outside of it

Comment: You could try this prebuilt image incl. chrome/angular-cli: https://hub.docker.com/r/trion/ng-cli-karma/

Comment: I don't understand why I have to download docker. For you, it is not a configuration problem ? Docker allows travis to find a Browser to execute 'ng test' ?

Comment: The docker image is specially crafted to allow painless execution of browser based tests in headless environments (f.e. Travis CI). You don't have to use it, but is makes life much easier: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/#using-a-docker-image-from-a-repository-in-a-build

Comment: Thank you for this idea, but I found another way. I just put the option --watch=false for ng test, and changed export CHROME_BIN=usr/bin/google-chrome by export CHROME_BIN=chronium-browser. It is working

Comment: Another benefit when using a docker image: You don't have to install all dependencies, reducing the build time usually.

Comment: I am going to try what you say, thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue.
I just changed export CHROME_BIN=usr/bin/google-chrome in .travils.yml by export CHROME_BIN=chromium-browser, and added an option --watch=false for ng test.